# Modifying tuples within list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have input of times like this:

```
09:00 12:00
10:00 13:00
11:00 12:30
12:02 15:00
09:00 10:30
```

I am trying to built it into a list of tuples, converted to minutes:

```
[(540, 720), (600, 780), (660, 750), (722, 900), (540, 630)]
```

I want a cleaner, more Pythonic way of doing the conversion. I currently have a clumsy way of doing this:

```
def readline(): 
    return sys.stdin.readline().strip().split()

natimes = [tuple(readline()) for _ in xrange(linesofinput))]
for i, (a,b) in enumerate(natimes):
    c = int(a.split(':')[0])* 60 + int(a.split(':')[1])
    d = int(b.split(':')[0])* 60 + int(b.split(':')[1])
    natimes[i] = (c,d)
```

Just doesn't feel like I'm using Python properly here.

Comment: You could turn the 'for' into a 'map' instead.  That would help a little.  I'm sure there are other things too. Admittedly though, you're chopping the string in half and doing a computation on both halves so I don't think it will get that much better.  At some point, if it works, it works.

Comment: Why is this titled "Lambda function for tuples within list" (and tagged "lambda") when you don't have any `lambda`s, don't mention them in the description, and don't seem to have any good reason to want one?

Comment: Whenever your code looks clumsy, with a complex expression, or multiple similar lines, factor it out into assignments to intermediate variables and/or named functions, and you'll have a better handle on how to make it more readable. Or, as mgilson's answer shows, you may be done at that point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use functions:

```
def time_to_int(time):
    mins,secs = time.split(':')
    return int(mins)*60 + int(secs)

def line_to_tuple(line):
    return tuple(time_to_int(t) for t in line.split())

natimes = [line_to_tuple(line) for line in sys.stdin]
```

Answer (score 2):

Avoid duplicating expensive operations like `str.split`. Below is a simple answer:

```
>>> print(s)
09:00 12:00
10:00 13:00
11:00 12:30
12:02 15:00
09:00 10:30
>>> def to_minutes(s):
...     hour, min = map(int, s.split(":"))
...     return hour * 60 + min
... 
>>> to_minutes("12:30")
750
>>> res = []
>>> for i1, i2 in map(str.split, s.split("\n")):
...     res.append((to_minutes(i1), to_minutes(i2)))
... 
>>> res
[(540, 720), (600, 780), (660, 750), (722, 900), (540, 630)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option, using regular expressions:

```
import re
regex = re.compile('\s*(\d\d):(\d\d)\s+(\d\d):(\d\d)\s*')
natimes = []

for line in sys.stdin.readline():
    m = regex.match(line)
    if m:
        natimes.append((int(m.group(1))*60 + int(m.group(2)),
                        int(m.group(3))*60 + int(m.group(4))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it (but using a data string instead for this example):

```
data = """09:00 12:00
10:00 13:00
11:00 12:30
12:02 15:00
09:00 10:30
"""

def minutes(s):
    hr, min = s.split(":")
    return int(hr) * 60 + int(min)

rv = []
for line in data.splitlines(): # may also use readlines from a file object
    rv.append(tuple([minutes(s) for s in line.split()]))

rv
# OUT: [(540, 720), (600, 780), (660, 750), (722, 900), (540, 630)]
```

Comment: You can get rid of brackets in that list comprehension to convert it to a pretty generator expression.